# Theano: ifelse TypeError

Tags: python, theano

I am trying to run the script [lstm_ptb.py](https://github.com/wenbinli/lstm) but it is throwing a TypeError for the following line:

```
shrink_factor = ifelse(T.gt(norm_gparams,max_grad_norm),max_grad_norm/norm_gparams,1.)
```

This is what this line is trying to achieve:

```
 if norm_gparams > max_grad_norm: 
    shrink_factor = max_grad_norm/norm_gparams
 else:
    shrink_factor = 1.
```

It says:

> TypeError: The two branches should have identical types, but they are TensorType(float64, scalar) and TensorType(float32, scalar) respectively. This error could be raised if for example you provided a one element list on the `then` branch but a tensor on the `else` branch

How to resolve the error please? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your problem caused by `1.` in `else` part. By default it assigned as `float32` type. You just need to convert it:

```
shrink_factor = ifelse(T.gt(norm_gparams,max_grad_norm),max_grad_norm/norm_gparams,np.float64(1.))
```

or convert the `max_grad_norm/norm_gparams` value:

```
shrink_factor = ifelse(T.gt(norm_gparams,max_grad_norm),(max_grad_norm/norm_gparams).astype('float32'),1.)
```

so both value have the same type